# What is this aquatic organism in Fiji?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

I found them under reefs in Fiji. The hand-like structures moved slowly. I was not sure if it was an animal or plant. I was not even sure if they were several individuals or it was a whole.
The part that was not hidden by the stone was about 50cm length. I did not touch them, since I was not sure if it was dangerous.

Comment: What size is this?

Comment: the part which was not hidden was 50cm length.  I did not touch them, since i was not sure if it was dangerous.

Comment: They seem like sea-cuecamber (Holothuroidea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably Holothuria leucospilota

Holothuria leucospilota is a medium-sized sea cucumber reaching a length of up to 40 centimetres (16 in) when relaxed but it can stretch to about a metre (yard) when extended.

Holothuria leucospilota is found in shallow water along the east coast of Africa and in much of the Indo-Pacific region. It is a common species on the north east coast of Australia where it is found on reefs and rocky coasts, often partly concealed under a boulder.

References
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holothuria_leucospilota

Comment: Please provide more explanation, links, etc., that help others understand why you think this is the answer.